# Create and set Connector dynamically for endpoint

Tags: java, mule, mule-el

I have an outbound-endpoint, but I would like to create and set a connector dynamically for the endpoint using Java, before the endpoint actually sends a file.

I have found an example on creating a connector dynamically, as in:

```
    As2Connector connector = new As2Connector(muleContext);
    connector.setName("TestAS2Connector");
    connector.setPartnerId("mend");
    connector.setKeystorePath("src/test/resources/keystoreTest.jks");
    connector.setKeystorePassword("PASSWORD");
    return connector;
```

However, I do not know how to tie the connector with my existing endpoint. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: The reason I want to create the connector dynamically is because I want to set the partnerId attribute dynamically. I don't think it can be set using a mule expression with a different value depending on the inbound message, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the MuleClient create the endpoint for you and configure the connector on it, like:

```
muleClient.send("as2://...?connector=TestAS2Connector", ...);
```

Comment: Interesting. And if I were to append ?connector=TestAS2Connector in the address="" attribute of my actual endpoint element, would it work? I'm wondering if I could just do ?connector=#['dynamicEndpointName'] and be done with it :). Worth a try!

Comment: You say "endpoint element": does it mean you configure the endpoint by XML not by code? In that case, there's a `connector` attribute on the element you can use.

Comment: Yes, by endpoint element, I meant the outbount-endpoint XML element, sorry for the confusion. So I'm assuming the connector attribute could indeed take a mule expression holding a reference to the connector dynamically created, or maybe it would simply take its name, like in your example with the muleClient.send() call. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Just take the name but make sure to first register it with the object registry, otherwise it won't be found by Spring and the injection will fail. This is tricky business because you need to populate the registry with this custom connector while initializing Mule... It would be easier to use the MuleClient or the requester module (which wraps it) to make a completely dynamic outbound interaction instead of using the XML element.